# Проблема с Кэшом страницы

Tags: html, кэширование

Всем привет.

Есть сайт, на котором были фото. Заменил эти фото, наименование фото оставил те же, чтобы не править код. Но фото старые по прежнему. Чищу `cache`, фото появляются новые. А вот вопрос, можно как то автоматически очистить `cache`, что бы у всех пользователей уже появились новые фото?

Comment: Правильнее всего именно что менять имена фото.